# Expect Script - awk say variable doesn't exist

Tags: awk, grep, expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set name [lindex $argv 0]

send  "grep $name /usr/local/bin/c | awk '{print $3}' | awk '{print substr($1,10)}'\r"
spawn  grep $name /usr/local/bin/c | awk '{print $3}' | awk '{print substr($1,10)}'
```

I have tried "\" escaping quotes and special symbols. It doesn't work. I also have tried to send and spawn. Doesn't work. If I run just the grep........... command on the line it returns what I need. Any help on how to get this to run from my expect file would be great. Thanks.

Comment: First simplify your command - you don't need grep, 2 awks, and pipes for this task. If you were to run it on the command line it'd be `awk -v n="$name" '$0 ~ n{print substr($3,10)}' /usr/local/bin/c` so THAT is the command you should be trying to get working using expect. I'd start with trying to get a simpler command like `awk 'BEGIN{print "hello world"}'` to work though.

Comment: Thanks. I still get error: can't read "0": no such variable
    while executing
"spawn awk -v n="perferx" '$0 ~ n{print substr($3,10,5)}' /usr/local/bin/c". Any thoughts on what to try. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest you could simply plug that awk script into an expect script and it'd work, I was just saying that's the command-line script to start with. I already gave my thoughts on what to try - start with trying to get a simpler command like `awk 'BEGIN{print "hello world"}'` to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes have no special meaning in expect. Use braces instead for the same effect:

```
spawn awk -v n="perferx" {$0 ~ n {print substr($3,10,5)}} /usr/local/bin/c
# .......................^..............................^
```

Ref: [Tcl syntax rules, #6](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

> No substitutions are performed on the characters between the braces

---

Additionally, without seeing what you're doing with the output, perhaps you don't need `spawn`

```
set output [exec awk -v n="perferx" {$0 ~ n {print substr($3,10,5)}} /usr/local/bin/c]
```

Now, you can do simple string parsing on $output

Comment: This was what I needed to but it into a variable. Made it a lot easier to accomplish what I was doing. I did see this on a different post, but it wasn't very clear to me.

Comment: expect is a very useful tool, but it really does have a very narrow application. Once you realize that expect is built on Tcl and you have a powerful general purpose language to work will, things tend to simplify.